# How can I prioritize the y scale I get from geom_histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw a vertical line on a histogram where the median of my data are after faceting.  I'd like to do this with `stat_summary` as shown below.  The problem with this approach is that the y axis is not on the right scale

I think this is because I call `ggplot(aes(x=data,  y=data))`. Seems a bit strange to do for a histogram, but the reason I do this is because `stat_summary` requires a y aesthetic.  Is there a way I could plot the medians with `stat_summary` but keep the scale I get from when I call `geom_histogram`?  I could add a `ylim` but the problem with that approach is that I may not know what the right upper limit is a priori for new data I might see.

Below is a reprex to generate my example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.2

d = tribble(
  ~groupvar, ~data,
  'a', rlnorm(10,2, 0.5),
  'b', rlnorm(10,2, 0.5),
  'c', rlnorm(10,5, 0.5)
) %>% unnest(c(data))



d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = data, y = data, group = groupvar))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..))+
  facet_grid(~groupvar)+
  stat_summary(aes(x=0, xintercept=stat(y)), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete `y = ..count..` and map `y` only in the `stat_summary` layer:

```
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = data, group = groupvar))+
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(~groupvar) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = 0, xintercept=stat(x)), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
```

[image]

I also (a) removed the `x = 0` in the stat_summary layer and (b) changed `stat(y)` to `stat(x)` (since you're plotting a vertical line, makes sense for it to be a summary of the x values).

Comment: Thanks, but with other data this approach seems to make multiple vlines.  Here is a small example with the mpg dataset. `mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cty, group = cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(y=0, xintercept = stat(x)), geom = 'vline', fun = median)
`.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Specify `orientation = "y"` in the `stat_summary`. Can't say I really get it, but it works.