# Why does stat_summary plot multiple/single lines depending on the variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964074/how-can-i-prioritize-the-y-scale-i-get-from-geom-histogram) question a little bit ago.  In that, the solution seems to work *sometimes*.  Here is an example using the `mpg` data set.

My goal is to place a vertical line where the median of my data occur for each facet using `stat_summary`.  Note that when I use the solution in the linked question on the `displ` column, the solution works as desired.  But when I use it on the `cty` column, multiple lines are drawn.  Why is this?

Shown below is a reprex of my problem.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=displ, group=cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept=stat(x), y=0), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cty, group=cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept=stat(x), y=0), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demetri, here is the R code that will give you what you need:

```
library(tidyverse) 

g <- mpg %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x=cty)) + 
     geom_histogram() + 
     stat_summary(aes(x = 0, xintercept = stat(y), y = cty), 
                     fun.y = median, geom = "vline", colour = "red") + 
     facet_grid(~ cyl)


g
```

The stat_summary() function is set up to compute a summary (in this case, the median) for the variable specified in its y argument. In contrast, the geom_histogram() function creates a histogram for the variable specified in its x argument.  So you have to be careful with how you specify the y argument for the stat_summary() function, as seen in the code above.

Note that you dont't need to use *group = cyl* in your ggplot() call if you are using facet_grid() or facet_wrap() to produce multiple graphical panels.  Grouping and facetting are totally different plotting operations: grouping will show different data groups in the *same* panel; facetting will show different data groups in *different* panels.

**Addendum 1**

To check that the summary statistics were computed correctly for each panel, the command below will come in handy:

```
ggplot_build(g)$data
```

Scroll to the bottom of the output produced by this command to find the xintercept values used by R - these should be the medians plotted in the various panels. Alternatively, extract these values directly with:

```
ggplot_build(g)$data[[2]]
```

The xintercept values can be compared with independently computed median values of cty for each cyl level to ensure agreement.

**Addendum 2**

The default choice of binwidth for geom_histogram() needs some attention. You can try something like this to allow variable binwidth choice across your different panels:

```
theme_set(theme_bw())

g <- mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cty)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = function(x) 2 * IQR(x) / (length(x)^(1/3)), 
             fill = "lightblue3", colour = "white") + 
  stat_summary(aes(x = 0, xintercept = stat(y), y = cty), 
        fun.y = median, geom = "vline", colour = "red2") + 
  facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "free_x")


g
```

See this link for other possibilities of binwidth choice: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2312.

Comment: Thanks Isabella!

Comment: Oh, nice Isabella, was figuring this out as you went about it, thanks for this.

Comment: Yep, this was a bit of a counterintuitive beast!  I added an Addendum to my initial answer, showing how to combine my suggested solution with more decent choices of binwidths for the various histograms.

Comment: Well, I actually posted two addendums for anyone checking this answer. One shows how to retrieve the values of the medians displayed in each graphical panel and the other shows how to choose different binwidths for the different histograms.

Comment: @caldwellst:  I thought about converting cty from integer to numeric, but that didn't work. It was clever how you added a minute amount to cty to get the plot to work, though that hack is not desirable in practice.

Comment: Ha, yeah, definitely not desirable! Nice addendums, very useful.

Answer (score 4):

We can pre-compute the median using `group_by` and `mutate`, which I often find more reliable and easy to understand in its behavior, and then just use `geom_vline`. Can't answer on the `stat_summary` side, but interested to know the answer.

```r
mpg %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(cty_med = median(cty)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=cty))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=cty_med))
```

[image]

If you want to generalize this, you can just create a wrapper function that does your calculation and faceting together.

```r
f <- function(df, fct, var) {
  df %>%
    group_by({{fct}}) %>%
    mutate(med = median({{var}})) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x={{var}}))+
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_grid(cols = vars({{fct}})) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=med))
}

f(mpg, cyl, cty)
f(mpg, cyl, displ)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and I know this can be done, but this doesn't quite answer me question.  I will upvote but can't accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have made another post because I believe my exploration and solution are different enough from the original to justify it, but I can merge if anyone disagrees. So, I believe I have figured out what is the cause of the issue with `stat_summary` and your current solution.

I believe that `stat_summary` calculates its summary statistic for each unique value of `x`, when the `x` variable takes on integer values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

sapply(mpg, class)
#> manufacturer        model        displ         year          cyl        trans 
#>  "character"  "character"    "numeric"    "integer"    "integer"  "character" 
#>          drv          cty          hwy           fl        class 
#>  "character"    "integer"    "integer"  "character"  "character"
```

See below the same before when using `hwy` and `cty`, even when both explicitly converted to `numeric` rather than `integer` vectors.

```r
mpg2 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(hwy = as.numeric(hwy),
         cty = as.numeric(cty))

sapply(mpg2, class)
#> manufacturer        model        displ         year          cyl        trans 
#>  "character"  "character"    "numeric"    "integer"    "integer"  "character" 
#>          drv          cty          hwy           fl        class 
#>  "character"    "numeric"    "numeric"  "character"  "character"

mpg2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hwy, group=cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept=stat(x), y=0), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
```

[image]

And example with `cty`:

```r
mpg2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=cty, group=cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept=stat(x), y=0), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
```

[image]

However, if we make a slight adjustment to `cty` prior to plotting, adding a minute decimal point, we get the desired behavior.

```r
mpg %>%
  mutate(cty = cty + .000001) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=cty, group=cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept=stat(x), y=0), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
```

[image]

And we see the same behavior with `hwy`.

```r
mpg %>%
  mutate(hwy = hwy + .000001) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hwy, group=cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept=stat(x), y=0), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
```

[image]
Of course, this isn't necessarily a desirable solution. Since we are mapping vertical lines, we can instead create a new `aes` where we instead plot our `xintercept` as a function of `y`, and provide a single dummy variable to `x` within our data range. This then tricks the system into plotting only one median from our single `x` value, and gives us the desired graph.

```r
mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=cty, group = cyl))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~cyl)+
  stat_summary(aes(x = 3, y = cty, xintercept = stat(y)), fun = median, geom = 'vline')
```

[image]

And there we go! Quite convoluted, and don't really like it as a solution, but I believe this is the way you have to go if using `stat_summary`.